# Combinations of coins in stacks

Tags: combinatorics

I've come across this kind of problem multiple times and haven't been able to come up with an easy way to calculating the combinations.

Imagine you have n coins and m possible places to build stacks, how many ways are there to arrange the coins. Assuming building a stack using all coins in different places counts as a separate combination. It's not m^n because putting a coin in stack 1 then 2, is the same as 2 then 1.

A follow up question I have is, what if the stacks have a maximum height limit k.
and for example you have 10 coins, 4 positions and a height limit of 5. Each of the four stacks can only be filled to a height of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is $$m(m+1)(m+2)\cdots(m+n-1).$$ Imagine placing the coins one at a time. The first coin can go in $m$ places. The second coin can go in any of $m+1$ places: on the bottom of any of the $m$ stacks, or on top of the first coin. In general, the $i^{th}$ coin can be placed in $m+i-1$ places; on the bottom of any of the $m$ stacks, or just above any of the $i-1$ previously placed coins.

Suppose that each stack must have *less than* $k$ coins (note that you asked about $k$ *or less*; I make this change to make the answer look nicer). Then you can determine the number of ways to place the coins using the principle of inclusion exclusion. Here, I will use the notation $m^{\overline n}$ to denote $m(m+1)(m+2)\cdots(m+n-1)$. The answer is now
$$
\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^i\binom{m}i\binom{n}{ki}(ki)!\,m^{\overline{n-ki}}
$$
Brief explanation; take all $m^{\overline n}$ arrangement, then for each stack, subtract the arrangement where that stack has $k$ or more coins. You choose the $k$ coins on the bottom in $\binom{n}k$ ways, order them in $k!$ ways, then arrange the rest of the coins in $m^{\overline{n-k}}$ ways. However, the arrangements with two stacks with $k$ or more coins were doubly subtracted, so they must be added back in. Then you correct for the arrangements with three bad stacks, then four, etc.